# Upload file in database with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, input

I'm developing a website with Laravel in my localhost (in my local server), and in some part of my project I need to upload some XML files to generate a Excel file with phpexcel api. This is how my work proceed:

1 - I create xml files with forms and store them in my public directory in my projects

2- when I want to upload and use those xml files, I'm just taking the name from input and add them to an url to open the file stored localy ( something like this :)

```
$xml_tmu=simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

So my question is this: when I will upload my website in a server, do I need to store my xml files in a database so I can use them after, or they will be created in a public directory in the server (like the same thing in my local server)? And if not, what is the best solution to do so ?

Comment: How you store your data (file/db) is a separate concern. Personally, I wouldn't put uploads in the public directory, instead make a controller that takes the file name and uses `fopen()` instead of performing an HTTP request to the same server, which is kind of pointless and unnecessary. Then you can pass the contents in to your simple xml. Also, `DOMDocument` is way better than simple xml, check it out!

Comment: I think here you don't need to upload xml files as you are already converting them to excel file. And Dp not uploads the file in public directory

Comment: i undertand now that i don't have to store in public directory, but i need to save my xml file to use them after to generate an excel file, so please ? what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Well Jaffery way has defined some best practice on file uploading in this episode you can watch this: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a database if you don't want to use a database to store files in your server.

If you have an usual Laravel app running on your remote server, you probably have a writable `storage` folder in the root of your application directory, so you can probably do

```
$xmlFilename = 'whatevernameyouneedhere.xml';

$xml_tmu = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

Storage::put($xmlFilename, $xml_tmu);
```

And then you can get it back using

```
$xml = Storage::get($xmlFilename);
```

It works locally or remotely, if, of course, your storage folder is writable to the webserver user (nginx, apache2, www-data....)